# Determinant of $A^T D A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ tall matrix ($n > m$) and let $D$ be a diagonal $n \times n$ matrix. Is the following correct?

$$\det\left( A^T D A \right) = \det \left( A^T A \right) \det(D)$$

Comment: What facts do you know about the determinant of a product of matrices, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I know if the matrices A, B, C are invertible then $det(ABC)=det(A)det(B)det(C)$, $det(A^TA)$ is not always equal to $det(AA^T)$. 

$A^TDA$ is a symmetric matrix, therefore there is a relation between the singular values of $A^TD^{1/2}$ and the determinant.

Comment: A is tall, we can assume that $rank(A)=m$, where $m < n$.

Comment: This already fails when $D=cI$ and $c$ is a real or complex scalar such that $|c|\ne\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Counterexample:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix},\;D=\begin{bmatrix}d_1&0\\0&d_2\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $A^TDA$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, it is equal to its determinant:
$$A^TDA=d_1a^2+d_2b^2=\det(A^TDA)$$
Similarly, $\det(A^TA)=A^TA=a^2+b^2$, while $\det(D)=d_1d_2$.

One can see that
$$d_1a^2+d_2b^2\neq d_1d_2(a^2+b^2)$$
Therefore,
$$\det(A^TDA)\neq\det(A^TA)\det(D)$$